# Extract the Square Root of $ a^2-\left(\frac{\left(3a \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(3 \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)+\frac{41a}{16}+1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Extract the Square Root of $$ a^2-\left(\frac{\left(3a \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(3 \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)+\frac{41a}{16}+1 $$

I found a method to do this in a book but couldn't understand how to do it. Can anyone explain it?

[image: Book image]

Comment: Beats me...though there seems to be some logic in the steps. This most surely is explained somewhere *before* this page. This looks like some kind of weird (to me) synthetic division...

Comment: There is nothing for extracting the square.

Comment: Which book${}$?

Comment: Hua's Introduction to Higher Mathematics

Comment: I agree with DonAntonio, the book author had to have explained this method before applying it

Comment: This is the method analogous to long division.  See another answer of mine [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889933/finding-square-root/1890078#1890078).  Indeed, that's an old-school stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be checking that $16a^2 - 24a^{\frac{3}{2}} + 41a - 24a^{\frac{1}{2}} + 16$ is a perfect square of a linear expression of the form $c_1 a + c_2 a^{\frac{1}{2}} + c_3$ for certain constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$ using some technique.  Note that squaring that linear expression gives
$$\left( c_1 a + c_2 a^{\frac{1}{2}} + c_3 \right)^2 = c_1^2 a^2 + 2c_1 c_2 a^{\frac{3}{2}} + \left(c_2^2 + 2c_1 c_3\right) a \; + 2c_2 c_3 a^{\frac{1}{2}} + c_3^2$$
Equating the coefficients of the terms with the original equation gives the following set of equations:
$$\begin{align}
c_1^2 & = 16 \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
2c_1 c_2 & = -24 \tag{2}\label{eq2} \\
c_2^2 + 2c_1 c_3 & = 41 \tag{3}\label{eq3} \\
2c_2 c_3 & = -24 \tag{4}\label{eq4} \\
c_3^2 & = 16 \tag{5}\label{eq5} \\
\end{align}$$
From \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq5}, we can see that $c_1$ and $c_3$ are $\pm 4$. From \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq4}, if $c_2$ is non-zero, then $c_1 = c_3$.  Checking using the positive case for $c_1$ gives from these $2$ equations that $c_2$ is $-3$.  This can be confirmed using \eqref{eq3}.  Thus, the linear expression is what the book shows as the denominator, i.e., $4a - 3a^{\frac{1}{2}} + 4$.  The negative case of $c_1 = c_3 = -4$ gives the other square root of the equation.

As for what the book is doing, it seems to be some sort of short hand for what I just did above.  If I took the time & effort, I could possibly figure it out, but it's getting too late for me to do that tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would love to figure out their method too.

Answer (score 2):

Let see an easier example: take square root of $a^2-4a+4$.

By the method given in the source:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

Note: In your example, you practically do the same operations. Also, you double $(-3)\cdot 2=-6$ and multiply $8\cdot 4=32$. Also, note in your example, the minus sign is already considered, so you don't subtract, but add.

Comment: Why? Because the arrows are distractive?

Comment: For me the other two answers are just alternatives, they are not attempting to explain the book's method and that was the OP's question. The arrows and description (you call them mess) show the meanings of the numbers.

Comment: Is there a name for this method or it just called long division method? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It is called square root algorithm. You can see [here](https://planetmath.org/SquareRootOfPolynomial) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324385/algorithm-for-finding-the-square-root-of-a-polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sqrt{a}$, then

$$ a^2-\left(\frac{\left(3a \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(3 \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)+\frac{41a}{16}+1 $$

$$ = {16x^4 -24x^3+41x^2 -24x+16\over 16}$$

$$ = ({4x^2+bx+4 \over 4})^2$$

where you have to find $b$. This is easy to do, just put some walue for $x$ , say $x=1$ in both expresions:

$$ {25\over 16} = {(8+b)^2\over 16}\implies b+8= \pm 5$$
Trying both values we see that $b=-3$ works and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2-\left(\frac{\left(3a \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)+\frac{41a}{16}-\left(\frac{\left(3 \sqrt{a}\right)}{2}\right)+1$$

For convenience, let $x=\sqrt a$. Then we get

$$x^4-\dfrac 32x^3 +\frac{41}{16}x^2-\dfrac 32x+1$$

Use of the square root algorithm would produce this.

\begin{array}{r}
   && x^2 & -\dfrac 34x & +1\\
   &&---  &--- &--- &--- &---\\
   &\mid&x^4 &-\dfrac 32x^3 &+ \dfrac{41}{16}x^2 &-\dfrac 32x &+1 \\
&x^2 \mid & x^4 \\
&\mid&--- &--- &---\\
&\mid &&-\dfrac 32x^3 &+ \dfrac{41}{16}x^2 \\
&2x^2-\dfrac 34x \mid &&-\dfrac 32x^3 &+\dfrac{9}{16}x^2 \\
&\mid &&--- &--- &--- &--- \\
&\mid && &2x^2 &-\dfrac 32x &+1 \\
&2x^2-\dfrac 32x+1 \mid && &2x^2 &-\dfrac 32x &+1 \\
&&& &--- &--- &--- \\
&&&&&&0
\end{array}

Hence

$$a^2-\frac 32a\sqrt a+\frac{41}{16}a-\frac 32\sqrt a+1
  = \left(a - \dfrac 34\sqrt a + 1\right)^2$$